# Compiling ksymoops tool on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, kernel-panic

I need to build ksymoops tool as standalone for kernel panic analyse.

ksymoops source code can be downloaded from [this link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ksymoops/2.4.11-1ubuntu1)

When I compile it on Ubuntu 12.04 it shows error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(compress.o): In function `bfd_compress_section_contents':
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/compress.c:100: undefined reference to `compressBound'
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/compress.c:106: undefined reference to `compress'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(compress.o): In function `decompress_contents':
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/compress.c:61: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/compress.c:49: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/compress.c:59: undefined reference to `inflateReset'
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/compress.c:56: undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../lib/libbfd.a(plugin.o): In function `try_load_plugin':
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/plugin.c:134: undefined reference to `dlopen'
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/plugin.c:141: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/build/buildd/binutils-2.22/builddir-single/bfd/../../bfd/plugin.c:137: undefined reference to `dlerror'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ksymoops] Error 1
```

Comment: `ksymoops` is useless since kernel 2.6; see [`oops-tracing.txt`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/oops-tracing.txt) in the kernel documentation.

Comment: "ksymoops has been removed from the kernel.  It was always meant to be a free standing utility, not linked to any particular kernel version." I want to use this tool as standalone tool, I'm modifying driver for kernel and kernel panic at booting time

Comment: That quote dates back to 1999; things have changed since then.

Comment: I got it from hardkernel source code for Odroidxu3 board v3.10. Maybe I have to find other ways. Thanks for your comment @Stephen